# what's the meaning of "type tags" in nodejs

Tags: node.js

[assert.deepStrictEqual(actual, expected[, message])](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/assert.html#assert_assert_deepstrictequal_actual_expected_message) in nodejs's docs:

> Type tags of objects should be the same.

what's the meaning of "type tags"

```
const date = new Date();
const object = {};
const fakeDate = {};

Object.setPrototypeOf(fakeDate, Date.prototype);

// Different type tags:
assert.deepStrictEqual(date, fakeDate);
```

`typeof date` and `typeof fakeDate` ,The results are all `object`, but different type tags

Answer (score 2):

Type tags in Javascript, are referred to the word returned by `typeof`

For example for primitive values:

```
typeof({}) // returns 'object', this is the type tag
```

For non-primitive:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(new Date) // returns 'Date {}' this is the type tag
```

If `typeof` is used with Date it will returns `object` which is right, because that would be the type tag for the primitive value, this is why using `Object.getPrototypeOf` is more accurate.

In the firsts JS implementations, the type tag were stored the first 1–3 bits and the the remaining 29–31, contained the actual data.

What the NodeJS docs says, it's that the result of `Object.getPrototypeOf` function when comparing two objects has to be the same to be considered as equal.

Comment: `typeof date` and `typeof fakeDate` ,The results are all `object`, but different type tags

Comment: Right, getting the value with `Object.getPrototypeOf(....)` you will see the difference.

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(fakeDate) // returns Date {}`
`Object.getPrototypeOf(object) // returns {}`

That's why they're different.

Comment: in devTool, `Object.getPrototypeOf(date)`  `Object.getPrototypeOf(fakeDate) `, The results are all `Date.prototype`

Comment: You're reading Node.js v10.1.0 docs, so you have to check it out with this version.

Comment: I didn't get rid of my doubts, but thank you very much

Comment: From DevTools, you can use:
`Object.getPrototypeOf(fakeDate).constructor.name // returns Date`
`Object.getPrototypeOf(object).constructor.name // returns Object`

There you can appreciate the difference from the browser.

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(date)`  not `Object.getPrototypeOf(object)`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question that has been already answered, but I thought I might add that, although:

> In the first implementation of JavaScript, JavaScript values were
> represented as a type tag and a value. The type tag for objects was 0.
> null was represented as the NULL pointer (0x00 in most platforms).
> Consequently, null had 0 as type tag, hence the typeof return value
> "object".

Type tags can also refer to an object's `toStringTag`.

> The Symbol.toStringTag well-known symbol is a string valued property
> that is used in the creation of the default string description of an
> object. It is accessed internally by the Object.prototype.toString()
> method.

The value associated to the well-know [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) is used as the default string description of an object. Since every built-in object has a `toStringTag` value (except for `null` prototypes), it can be used to detect an object's class.

There's a package called `typetags` that has more information about it:  [typetags.org](https://typetags.org)